# Excel file saved by javamail API not readable to apache poi API

Tags: excel, apache-poi, jakarta-mail, xls, xlsx

I receive a file on email which I read using javamail API and save it onto disk directory

**MailExtractor.java**

```
    Multipart multiPart = (Multipart) message.getContent(); 
    int numberOfParts = multiPart.getCount(); 
    for (int partCount = 0; partCount < numberOfParts; partCount++) { 
     MimeBodyPart part = (MimeBodyPart) multiPart.getBodyPart(partCount); 
     if (Part.ATTACHMENT.equalsIgnoreCase(part.getDisposition())) { 
       // this part is attachment 
       String fileName = part.getFileName(); 
       attachFiles += fileName + ", "; 
       part.saveFile(saveDir + File.separator + fileName); 
     } 
     else { 
       // this part may be the message content 
       messageContent = part.getContent().toString(); 
     }
    }
```

Now another program polls that disk directory and reads all incoming file. I am only concerned with File extensions - xls/xlsx, so I use apache poi to read the files:

```
/AvailabilityDirectoryPoller.java 
FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream(file); 
 Workbook wb = null; 
 Sheet sheet = null; 
 if(FilenameUtils.getExtension(file.getName()).equalsIgnoreCase("xls")){ 
   wb = new HSSFWorkbook(fs);   //line no 178 
   sheet = (HSSFSheet)wb.getSheetAt(0); 
 } 
 else{ 
   wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fs); 
   sheet = (XSSFSheet)wb.getSheetAt(0); 
 }
```

This sometimes(read random) results in error as below

```
[2013-07-18 23:38:32,409] ERROR [AvailabilityDirectoryPoller]: Exception in I/O Reading file 
java.io.IOException: Your file contains 79 sectors, but the initial DIFAT array at index 1 referenced block # 98. This isn't allowed and  your file is corrupt 
    at org.apache.poi.poifs.storage.BlockAllocationTableReader.<init>(BlockAllocationTableReader.java:103) 
    at org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.POIFSFileSystem.<init>(POIFSFileSystem.java:151) 
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.<init>(HSSFWorkbook.java:322) 
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.<init>(HSSFWorkbook.java:303) 
    at com.db.mmrepo.app.avl.bespoke.AvailabilityDirectoryPoller.process(AvailabilityDirectoryPoller.java:178) 
    at com.db.mmrepo.app.avl.bespoke.AvailabilityDirectoryPoller.fileFound(AvailabilityDirectoryPoller.java:73) 
    at org.sadun.util.polling.DefaultListener.receive(DefaultListener.java:43) 
    at com.deltax.util.listener.SignalQueue.run(Unknown Source)
```

If I put open the saved file in MS Excel, it opens woth no warnings/errors.

Comment: Sounds like an apache-poi problem since the saved file opens in Excel.  Are you sure you're not reading the file at the same time it's being written?  Also, be careful using the filename in the part, it could be full or garbage or things like "..".

Comment: @Mak: I have seen you have asked the same question on other sites also. However take a look on http://grokbase.com/t/nutch/user/118y1sjezb/nutch-1-3-difat-array-ioexception-on-parsing-files perhaps this issue was caused by file.content.limit or http.content.limit. I am not sure but may this will be helpful for you.